# For jPasskit for apple wallet , Is there an option to check if passes were already created?

Tags: apple-wallet

Using jPasskit for Apple™ PassKit Web Service.Please let me know how can we check if passes are already there for the particular loyalty card.

Scenario is like we should identify if passes are already added to apple wallet, then we should not allow user to create pass again.

Scenario is like we should identify if passes are already added to apple wallet, then we should not allow user to create pass again. Need help with https://github.com/drallgood/jpasskit

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of Apple's registration callbacks: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/register_a_pass_for_update_notifications

If you want to skip all that, you can use a service like passninja.com or passkit.com